# RETURN value to variable from query within stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Distribute 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    DECLARE @COMPANYID VARCHAR(MAX);
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Determine who has the large queue
    SELECT TOP 1 COMPANYID, COUNT(COMPANYID) AS 'Count', WorkerName
    FROM   TABLE
    WHERE  WorkerName IN ( 'Jimmy', 'Sally' )
    AND COMPANYID = @COMPANYID
    GROUP  BY COMPANYID, WorkerName
    ORDER BY COUNT(COMPANYID) DESC

    RETURN

END
GO
```

I would like to put the return value into a variable so i can do some more logic in the store procedure further down?

The workerName needs to be returned to a variable which i need to use for something else.

Comment: What return value? The ID? The COUNT? Both? Something else?

Comment: The worker name you've hard-coded into the query? Do you want Jimmy, or Sally? Or both?

Comment: Well the logic to determine the largest queue is already handled by the ORDER BY... so i just need to determine the name of the worker into a variable so i can use it to insert the record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get it into a variable:

```
declare @WorkerName as varchar(max)

select
     @WorkerName = WorkerName
from (
   SELECT TOP 1 COMPANYID, COUNT(COMPANYID) AS 'Count', WorkerName
   FROM   TABLE
   WHERE  WorkerName IN ( 'Jimmy', 'Sally' )
   AND COMPANYID = @COMPANYID
   GROUP  BY COMPANYID, WorkerName
   ORDER BY COUNT(COMPANYID) DESC
) _Worker
```

From here, you can use it in your procedure, change to a function with a return value, or use an output parameter to send it back to the caller.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a direct answer to your question but if all your stored procedure is supposed to do is retrieve a top row and return one of its columns as an output parameter, you might do better by converting it into an inline table-valued function:

```
-- of course, you need to DROP PROCEDURE dbo.name
-- prior to creating a function by the same name
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Distribute
    @COMPANYID VARCHAR(MAX)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    --Determine who has the large queue
    SELECT TOP 1 COMPANYID, COUNT(COMPANYID) AS [Count], WorkerName
    FROM   TABLE
    WHERE  WorkerName IN ( 'Jimmy', 'Sally' )
    AND COMPANYID = @COMPANYID
    GROUP  BY COMPANYID, WorkerName
    ORDER BY COUNT(COMPANYID) DESC
;
```

This will give you much flexibility for various situations. For instance, you could just return the row as is:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Distribute(...);
```

or insert it into a table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTargetTable (...)
SELECT ... FROM dbo.Distribute(...);
```

Or, if, as in your present situation, you needed to store the value of `WorkName` into a variable, you could do this:

```
SELECT @WorkName = WorkName FROM dbo.Distribute(...);
```

Moreover, you would be able to return results for a *column* of arguments (and use them in the same query):

```
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.SomeTable AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.Distribute(t.ArgumentColumn) AS d
WHERE d.WorkerName = ...  -- for an example
;
```

A similar flexibility could be achieved with a stored procedure too, albeit with more coding. You could return the results both as output parameters and as a row. You would still be unable to use the results of the SP in a query directly, same as the results of an equivalent inline TVF.

As a final note, I'd like to emphasise that for the best effect the function should be an *inline* TVF, not a *multi-statement* TVF. When "seeing" the former in a complex query, the query planner can (and does) blend the function's body with the rest of the query, which enables the planner to come up with the best execution plan possible.